# filter result rows to have alternating state in time series

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

Using standard TSQL the result i need has rows with an alternating binary BIT state in DATETIME order, the source rows are in DATETIME order but have redundant states, meaning there was no change in state from the previous row.

Source Rows:

```
State   Date
1       2019-06-01 09:00:00.000
0       2019-06-02 00:00:00.000
1       2019-06-02 15:00:00.000
1       2019-06-03 00:00:00.000 - redundant
1       2019-06-03 09:00:00.000 - redundant
1       2019-06-04 09:00:00.000 - redundant
0       2019-06-04 09:15:00.000
1       2019-06-04 09:45:00.000
1       2019-06-05 09:00:00.000 - redundant
0       2019-06-06 09:00:00.000
1       2019-06-07 09:00:00.000
0       2019-06-07 12:15:00.000
```

In pseudo SQL, the query to solve my problem would look like this:

```
SELECT State, Date 
FROM Source_Rows
WHERE State <> (State from previous row)
ORDER BY Date
```

Expected Result:

```
State   Date
1       2019-06-01 09:00:00.000
0       2019-06-02 00:00:00.000
1       2019-06-02 15:00:00.000
0       2019-06-04 09:15:00.000
1       2019-06-04 09:45:00.000
0       2019-06-06 09:00:00.000
1       2019-06-07 09:00:00.000
0       2019-06-07 12:15:00.000
```

**^** state column alternates 1-0-1-0-1-0-1

Comment: What is your SQL SERVER version?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU1) (KB4470220) - 12.0.6205.1 (X64) 
 Nov 30 2018 02:59:03 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LAG` function to compare current state with previous:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(State) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS PrevState
    FROM t
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE State <> PrevState OR PrevState IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x.[Date]) AS RId,
    x.*
    INTO #TblStateDate
FROM
(   
    SELECT 1 AS [State],'2019-06-01 09:00:00.000' AS [Date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 0 AS [State],'2019-06-02 00:00:00.000' AS [Date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS [State],'2019-06-02 15:00:00.000' AS [Date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS [State],'2019-06-03 00:00:00.000' AS [Date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS [State],'2019-06-03 09:00:00.000' AS [Date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS [State],'2019-06-04 09:00:00.000' AS [Date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 0 AS [State],'2019-06-04 09:15:00.000' AS [Date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 0 AS [State],'2019-06-04 09:30:00.000' AS [Date] UNION ALL --redundant extra added
    SELECT 1 AS [State],'2019-06-04 09:45:00.000' AS [Date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS [State],'2019-06-05 09:00:00.000' AS [Date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS [State],'2019-06-05 09:15:00.000' AS [Date] UNION ALL --redundant extra added
    SELECT 1 AS [State],'2019-06-05 09:15:15.000' AS [Date] UNION ALL --redundant extra added
    SELECT 0 AS [State],'2019-06-06 09:00:00.000' AS [Date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS [State],'2019-06-07 09:00:00.000' AS [Date] UNION ALL
    SELECT 0 AS [State],'2019-06-07 12:15:00.000' AS [Date] UNION ALL --redundant extra added
    SELECT 0 AS [State],'2019-06-07 12:30:00.000' AS [Date] UNION ALL --redundant extra added 
    SELECT 0 AS [State],'2019-06-07 12:45:00.000' AS [Date]           --redundant extra added 
) x

SELECT 
    t1.[State],
    t1.[Date]
FROM #TblStateDate t1
LEFT JOIN #TblStateDate t2 ON t2.RId = t1.RId - 1
WHERE (t1.[State] <> t2.[State] OR t2.[State] IS NULL)

DROP TABLE #TblStateDate;
```

Explanation: This query can be use from SQL Server 2005 onward versions by finding previous state value using record identity column.

Note: I have added extra redundant records in select union all script. Still you will get your expected result.

Ref. URL for search previous value: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/25/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement-part-4/